# jQuery error in using css function after get function

Tags: jquery

It seems the syntax below is wrong because I am getting an error "css is not a function" in Firefox. What's the correct syntax? I am trying to add a css property to the first object in the set.

```
$("div[id$='rvReport']").get(0).css("overflow", "auto");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `.get()`. Instead, use [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/):

```
$("div[id$='rvReport']").first().css("overflow", "auto");
```

You can also use [.eq(0)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the first element. It'll work the same, the only difference being that it's more flexible if you want to return an element that isn't first.

Comment: `[0].css()` doesn't work since `[0]` returns a DOM element, and not a jQuery object...

Comment: Thank you Sime. Changed by question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead.

```
$("div[id$='rvReport']").eq(0).css("overflow", "auto");
```

You could also use [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) for readability.